# Magento: simple stock indicator with css

Tags: css, magento, retina-display, magento-1.6, hdpi

I was looking for a simple stock indicator.

Comment: How does css relate to screen resolution(other then positioning)?

Comment: @boruch if you use an image it's not crisp. You need to images. http://d3pr5r64n04s3o.cloudfront.net/articles/075_retina_display/css-20120309-102836.jpeg

Comment: That depends on the quality...

Comment: @boruch if you want to support normal dpi and hdpi you have to create to images. For example one 16x16px and one 32x32px. It's more hassle to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your yourTheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml where you want the stock indicator.

```
<?php

    $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

    switch ($qty) {
        case $qty > 5 :
        $stockcss .= 'stockindicator-green';
        $stocktext = "In stock";
        break;
        case $qty <= 5:
        $stockcss .= 'stockindicator-green';
        $stocktext = "Low stock";
        break;
        case $qty <= 0:
        $stockcss .= 'stockindicator-green';
        $stocktext = "Out of stock";
        break;
    }
?>

Stock: <div class="stockindicator <?php echo $stockcss ?>" title="<?php echo $stocktext ?>"></div>
```

Add the code below to /skin/frontend/yourTheme/default/css/styles.css

```
.stockindicator {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}

.stockindicator-green { background-color: #46A40E; }
.stockindicator-yellow { background-color: #F9E700; }
.stockindicator-red { background-color: #E42620; }
```